# What cases exist for the new iPad (3rd generation) most similar to Apple's 1st generation case?

Tags: ipad, hardware-recommendation, case

I am looking for cases that fit the full size iPad with retina displays (3rd and 4th generation) and function similarly to the original black case from Apple for the first generation iPad.

The aspects most appealing from that original design were:

- slim - visually and form fitting without adding the bulk of an Otterbox product.
- wedge for two angles (yes the vertical placement wasn't the most stable)
- no covers on the screen or the ports letting all charging cables and controls work well
- light drop, scratch and bump protection
- durable (having seen over 25 case designs wear over 6+ months - the Apple one is surprisingly durable)
- reputable warranty service (you can call for an exchange without hassle if it starts tearing 6 months into use)

The closest case (that isn't shipping yet) I have seen is the [incase Magazine Jacket](http://goincase.com/products/detail/magazine-jacket-cl60129/3). What cases meet any (or many) of the criteria listed above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found anything third party, but Apple now makes the [iPad Smart Case](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD454LL/A/ipad-smart-case-polyurethane-dark-gray) that is almost perfect for the use case I have described above.

[image: polyurethane smart case for retina iPad]

<sup>Image from the [Apple store link](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD454LL/A/ipad-smart-case-polyurethane-dark-gray) above.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There is a new company launching on November 5th called [domeoproducts.com](http://www.domeoproducts.com). They are a company that makes iPad and iPad mini cases. I have seen a couple of pictures of them online, and they look awesome.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. We do welcome self-promotion with the understanding you self-disclose and also participate in general and not just to link to your product. Welcome!